# Adding DB connection through Visual Studio 2010 server explorer

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to connect to the database through vs2010, but getting the following error while trying:

> "The server was not found or was not accessible!"

The database is connected in SQL Server Management Studio and I am trying to access it from Visual Studio.

What could be the possible reason? 
What can I try?

[image: dbvserr]

Comment: u dont have name intance of ur sqlserver

Comment: as in?? well ADITYA-PC\SQLEXPRESS doesnt work either (if thats what you mean)...

Answer (score 0):

Is PC-Aditya the real name of your server? Since you can connect with SSMS, can you check the results of the following query

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS SERVERNAME
```

Can you specify the server as . and .\SQLEXPRESS ? or using localhost?

Lastly you could run the IPCONFIG command in your command prompt and use the IP address to connect to your server

```
e.g. 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.1.1\SQLExpress
```